# Whenever I upgrade my face rig then after generate rig there is an error and it doesn't show up (Rigify Error)

Tags: rigify

[image]

whenever I upgrade it then generate rig an error happens, any reasons why. Error message: *RIGIFY ERROR : Bone ‘jaw_master’ : Mouth corner counts differ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Janz gives the solution at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.blender.org/T96376):

It comes from a problem of symmetry, you need to reset everything:

- In *Object* mode select the armature, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- In the *Transform Pivot Point* panel choose *3D Cursor*
- In *Edit* mode select all the central bones (nose, chin, but also head of the central lips,etc) and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

- In *Edit* mode select all the bones and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset rotations

Comment: thanks!! it really helped a lot, one more thing. I scaled the rig at first, to the size of my mesh now when it spawns its small, do I scale it or is it another way to resize it to the same size as the metrig.                                           picture above

Comment: Please don't edit my answer if you don't plan to improve it, instead ask a new question as it is a completely different one. If you want to scale your armature and object, don't forget to apply the scale of both afterwards

Comment: I apologize, I am a nooby at stackexchange and didnt know I edited your answer also thanks! I was also being considerate of posting too many questions which was another reason, I apologize.